# Indicating that a paper-dropdown-menu is required

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

Is there a mechanism in dart-polymer to indicate that a paper-dropdown-menu is required similar to what can be done with a paper-input as placing required property on the menu does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation

- https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-dropdown-menu
- https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-dropdown-menu

doesn't mention validation.

You can either do it yourself by setting a red border or similar when no value is selected or
create a feature request in the GitHub repository (https://github.com/Polymer/paper-dropdown-menu/issues)

Comment: I would like to say that at this moment, paper-dropdown-menu already support 'required' attribute. (Polymer 1.7, 9.12.2016).
[documentation](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu)